# Using ip, what does LOWER_UP mean?

Tags: linux, terminal, ip

When using the terminal tool `ip`, there is a number of flags for every interface.

Example:
`eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000`

The meaning of `BROADCAST`, `MULTICAST` and `UP` is clear, but what does `LOWER_UP` mean? I tried to google for this, but I didn't find a clear answer. When another host is connected to this link, then state goes to `UP`, when it disconnects, state goes to `DOWN` and `LOWER_UP` disapears. Does this have something to do with the connection state?

**EDIT:**

I have found another interesting fact. When I set the connected interface to down (via `ip link set eth0 down`) on the other host (cable stays connected), the output changes to

`1: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000`

Then the `UP` flag is still present, but not the `LOWER_UP`. Shouldn't it be the opposite way?

Comment: now you certainly can :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`LOWER_UP` is a physical layer link flag (the layer below the network layer, where `IP` is generally located). `LOWER_UP` indicates that an Ethernet cable was plugged in and that the device is connected to the network.

`LOWER_UP` differs from `UP`, which additionally requires the network interface to be enabled.

Comment: nice explanation. Do you know of some example that can set UP or LOWER_UP programatically?

Answer (score 12):

It's described in man [`netdevice(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html), but not much meaningful to me:

```
IFF_LOWER_UP      Driver signals L1 up (since Linux 2.6.17)
```

These comments are from [linux/if.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/include/linux/if.h) header file (in `enum net_device_flags`).